# babel package causes Missing \endcsname error when minted is used

Tags: babel, minted

On the tex file below, if I use the `babel` package along with the `minted` package, it gives this error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.1 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
```

My system is Tex Live 2020 on macOS 10.7.5 and the command is:

```
xelatex --shell-escape minted-tryin.tex
```

If I comment out all the `minted` related lines, it compiles fine when the `babel` is included.

How to use these both packages together?

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[british, turkish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{turkish}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Ok let's start...

\begin{minted}{python}
import sys, math
if (len(sys.argv)>1) :
    print (math.factorial(int(sys.argv[1])))
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mine is compiling with XeLaTeX... Are all of your packages up to date?

Comment: turkish makes `=` into an active character (at least under pdflatex) and thus ends up in  trouble with some `key=value` interfaces like the ones behind `minted` (clue: `commandchars=` in the error)

Comment: @Enevevet Packages are as update as the 2020 version of Tex Live. I haven't updated any of the packages.

Comment: @daleif You seem to be on the right track because when I changed the language from turkish to spanish, it compiled fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `turkish` language will (under at least `pdflatex`) make `!:=` into active characters. You'll probably need to disable them around `minted` as it probably affect the `key=value` interface `minted` uses internally and because of the `:` in your example.

Adding this to the preamble seems to work

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{
  \shorthandoff{=}
  \shorthandoff{:}
}
```

I did not add `!` in my tests.